# Pause Execution in Excel VB Script

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I have the following script running an automatic update macro in an Excel spreadsheet, but I need it to pause to give the macro time to update the data before it closes.  I've tried multiple solutions I've found here, but I can't find one that will release the spreadsheet to close and quit when the data update is done.  Here's the script as it stands, any ideas would be appreciated:

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'~~> Change Path here
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Daily Update.xlsm", 0, False)

xlapp.displayalerts = false
xlApp.Run "RefreshData"
xlApp.Wait Now + 0.007
xlapp.displayalerts = true
xlBook.Close(False)
xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Daily Update Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Update:  It appears to be running fine if I run it manually, but when I run it with Task Scheduler, that is when it won't release.

Comment: Why are you refreshing the data then closing without saving  changes?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting for the macro `RefreshData` to finish and then closing the file, do it in your macro.

What I am doing is at the end of the macro, I am creating a blank text file at `C:\MyVBSFolder\`. Replace the path with your VBS folder path.

```
Sub RefreshData()
    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '

    Dim fso As Object
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oFile As Object
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\MyVBSFolder\CloseMe.Txt")
    oFile.Close
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing

    ThisWorkbook.Close (False)
End Sub
```

and then use it like this (**Untested**)

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'~~> Change Path here
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Daily Update.xlsm", 0, False)

xlApp.DisplayAlerts = False
xlApp.Run "RefreshData"

'~~> Replace the path with the vbs folder path
'~~> Check if the file was created. If it was then quit
'~~> Excel application
Do While Dir("C:\MyVBSFolder\CloseMe.Txt") = "": DoEvents: Loop

xlApp.Quit

'~~> Delete the file
Kill "C:\MyVBSFolder\CloseMe.Txt"

Set xlBook = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Daily Update Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: Instead of `DoEvents` you may also use `xlApp.Wait Now +  Something`